# Ionic 3 - Working with cookies

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

I want to get the cookies data in my application and need to store it in backend. In my case, what actually I need is to capture the user activity in my app. Is it possible?. If yes, please help me

Thanks

Comment: for which type of project? website  or app(android/ios)?

Comment: I want to develop a hybrid mobile application using ionic framework for both android and ios platforms

Comment: Ok, you should use storage or sqlite plugin and not cookie. The Cookie is used for browsers and not app.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store user data is using Storage.

> "Storage uses a variety of storage engines underneath, picking the
>   best one available depending on the platform."

*Ionic Storage*: https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Comment: Thanks for your response, But I need to capture user's browsing history in entire app. Is it possible?. If yes, please help me out of this

Answer (score 0):

If I needed to get all user's browsing history then I would use a database instead of local storage, if your're not using authentication in your app then I suggest you to get the device Id [unique-device-id](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/unique-device-id/) and with that you can save all browsing history from that device.